# For infinite dimension linear space's base as $S=\{(1,0,...),(0,1,...),...\}$, is $(1,1,...,1,...)$ is an element of the space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assume an infinite dimension linear space, its base is $S=\{(1,0,...),(0,1,...),...\}$.

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) if a vector $v$ is in this vector space, then I can choose a set of vector $\{v_1,...,v_n\}\subset S$ and a set of number as $a_1,...,a_n$ so that $v=\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i$

Now my question is weather $v=(1,1,...)$ (all $1$ in each dimension) is an element of this vector space. Because for any finite $n$ it cannot satisfy that $v=\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i$

In other words, is the indicator $n$ in the summation can be infinite??

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Counter-example: Consider the space $\ell^{0}$ of sequences of real numbers with only finitely many non-zero terms (under usual operations).

Comment: Hi sorry I'm learning and do not understand what $\mathcal{l}^0$ means, what key word I should search for definition of this, thanks!!!

Comment: @Shore: $\ell^0=\{(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}\mid a_i=0\text{ for all $i$ but finitely many}\}.$

Answer (score 1):

No, its not. Each element of the vector space must be a *finite* linear combination of a basis.

Answer (score 1):

No, by definition, it's easy to see that the  indicator $n$ in the summation must be finite.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of completeness, let's add that there are other kinds of bases, where infinite linear combinations are accepted. This is especially useful for function spaces.

Cf.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Hamel_basis

But this requires to give a meaning to infinite linear combinations, so there needs to be some topological structure, in addition to the vector space structure.

So the usual, by-default definition, is that only finite linear combinations are allowed.